# Sequelize - include module while the where clause is optional

Tags: sequelize.js

Man Sequelize's support is bad.

I am trying to fetch all rows and include another table with a `where` clause being optional.

Given the following table (I know it has errors its just for demonstrational purposes).

```
var Event= sequelize.define('Event', {
  name: string,
  image: string
})

var Occurrence= sequelize.define('Occurrence', {
  date: date,
  eventId: number
})

//Association
Event.hasMany(Occurrence);
Occurrence.belongsTo(Event);
```

I would like to fetch all events including their occurrences while either `occurrence.date > now` or event doesnt have an occurrence at all.

So far I've tried several things:

```
const query = {
      where: {},
      include: {
        model: Occurrence,
        where: {
          date: {
            [Op.or]: {
              [Op.eq]: null,
              [Op.gte]: Date.now(),
            }
          },
        },
        //required: false
      }
    }
const rows = await Event.findAll(query);
```

Adding `required: false` will simply ignore occurrence all together and simple return all events. if an event's `occurrence.date` is at the past it should not select that event, however it does and just omit the occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

Having where condition inside included model inserts the condition with `ON` phrase in the join query, but here we need it in where condition after performing the join.
So the solution is to not give the where condition alongside the included model and mention it inside the main **findAll** query `where` object.

```js
const query = {
    where: {
        [Op.and]: {
            '$Occurrence.date$': {
                [Op.or]: {
                    [Op.eq]: null,
                    [Op.gte]: Date.now(),
                }
            }
        }
    },
    include: {
        model: Occurrence,
        required: false
    }
}
```

Reference: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html#complex-where-clauses-at-the-top-level